# Custom Function Entering the Result Array into a Different Cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have created my own function to determine count the values in between to given values in increments of 30 as seen here

```
Function InBetween(First As Integer, Last As Integer)
Dim i As Long, F As String, a() As String
F = First
For i = First + 30 To Last Step 30
F = F & "|" & i
Next i
InBetween = F
End Function
```

When I use this function, I currently have it returning the result array in the cell the formula was entered into in the format of "1|2|3|4". Is there a way I can get this array to populate into the cell below the one containing the formula?

Note: I don't want the formula in the cell as I need to refer to the cell in a future equation that will use the result and not the equation.

Comment: You can return an array from a function.  Having the formula in the cells will not be a problem if you want to feed those cells into other formulas.  You *will* need to enter the formula in at least as many rows as there will be elements in your return array.  See "returning arrays from functions" here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: what is the point of having a function if you are not returning anything from it? you can use a `Sub` as well. don't you mean `Function InBetween(First As Integer, Last As Integer) As String` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado the OP is returning a value.  As is the Function is returning a Variant.  Just like a variable that is undeclared.

Comment: Tim, I am hoping to split numbers in the array into different cells within a column so that I can use them for data validation

Answer (score 0):

This was surprisingly difficult. At first I tried calling a sub from the function to affect the cell below using application.caller but this always returned a #value error. It seems a UDF can't run anything that affects the worksheet.

Eventually I came up with this:

Create a worksheet change event by pasting this into the worksheet object in vb:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Left(Target.Offset(-1, 0).Formula, 10) = "=InBetween" Then Call DoX(Target.Offset(-1, 0), InBetween(10, 60))
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Then paste this into a module

```
Sub DoX(r As Range, val As String)

Sheets(r.Parent.Name).Cells(r.Row, r.Column) = ""
Sheets(r.Parent.Name).Cells(r.Row + 1, r.Column) = val

End Sub
```

Then use your function as normal, but remember to hit return after you enter it so the active cell is the cell below where you entered the formula.